# Performance of voting system (with account) implemented by using Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, voting-system

I'm currently creating a voting system with good and bad option for a comment. Basically, the idea is like facebook's one, but have a bad option(or more) for the comment. Here is the table structure

```
id | comment_id | voter_id | voter_option
```

So, once the user vote it, a record will be store in the mysql database on the above format, why I'm doing this is because I don't want the user re-vote, and want to record what they like/dislike.

my question is, I think, if there have 10,000 comments in my website, and each comments got 1,000 votes, then my database is become very large, are there any good method(example maybe) to prevent the database become too large? Or I need to create a table for each comments in my case, thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get a better responce if you tag this with MySql or whatever database  language your using.

Comment: Why not use a nosql solution like mongodb? seems ideal for this scenario

Comment: Could we get a further explanation of why mongodb would be ideal?

Comment: Well, it's document based and has super fast writes and reads. This means you're not going to have a lot of problems with large number of  up/down votes the users cast. Since the relational component of a ERD isn't required here (going from what the user posted here), you might as well switch to a nosql solution

Comment: Hi JohnP, I just read mongodb, and some of the user said, the data may corrupt, is that true, and how to prevent it if yes~?

Comment: And what if a lot of user making (select,update) in same time? Will it be process one-by-one, or can (select,update) simultaneously? thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

What does your comments table look like? The database will only get large if there's many posts, 10,000 entries in a table is childsplay for mysql if you query correctly and your table is a sane size.

Performance wise, it may be an idea that when someone likes/dislikes a comment, you do a tally of all the votes and store that value in the comment row, this way when you query out the comment you'll have its last known like/dislike count and don't have to do that counting each time you query for comments.

Edit: I should add, make sure your indexes are ints (judging by the column names they are) and you're using foreign keys for data restraints. With foreign keys you can keep your tables clean, for example, if someone deletes a comment you can tell your tables to delete cascade, based on that id, so the comment gets deleted, all of the votes for that comment get deleted from the other table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your counting method is very useful, preliminary, because I don't want to handle the comments myself so I may use disqus or facebook's comment(sorry haven't mention), but since both of them have only 1 option(like), and I need maybe more than 2 option, so I will handle the vote part, I can't estimate the number of user currently, maybe it just growth up suddenly, or nobody use (who knows :P).Do I need to do partitioning(I just heard this can help, but not really know what it is.:P) in the earlier stage? FYI, I'm using MyISAM.